# Call obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error: in an unsaved document

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I've run into a scenario where I need to store the order of Core Data entities in a to-many relationship. I was planning on using the permanent ID's of objects in the relationship, but the following code results in an error when called on an unsaved (untitled) document. (I'm hoping to achieve something similar to BWOrderedManagedObject.)

```
if(!widget)
{
    widget = [[Widget alloc] initWithContext:[delegate managedObjectContext]];

    NSError* error = nil;

    if(![[widget managedObjectContext] obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:widget] error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }
}
```

However, when `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` is called, it results in the following error:

> The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store.

Is there anyway I can obtain a permanent ID before the document has been saved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obtaining a permanent ID for an object needs to write out that object to the database. It is, in essence, saving the object, but in a special way. It's just as costly as a real save, and it absolutely requires you to have a store on-disk.